# how to use du -sh inside bash script

Tags: bash, du

I want to create a keeper on my jobs file on the HPC in the campus. Should my disk usage exceed 50GB I want all my jobs to stop (and possibly get an email about this). What I want to do is something of this sort:

```
#!/bin/bash

run=1
while [ $run -gt 0 ]; do
  a=du -sh ~
  if [ $a -gt 50GB ]; then
    run=0
    break
  fi
done

qdel j*fd
qdel j*fd
#send email in some way
```

I am stuck in two things:

1. I can't use du -sh inside a script, I get an error:

   -sh: command not found
2. I don't how to compare the sizes.

how can I achieve this?

Comment: correct command is `a=$(du -sh ~)` the command `a=du -sh ~` means `-sh ~` with environnement variable `a=du`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: it does, line 5

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, how can I compare the sizes?

Comment: @Yotam: No, line 5 doesn't run the `du` command, as Nahuel explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `a=$(du_command)`. `a=du -sh ~` is equivalent to `-sh ~` with environment variable `a=du`
2. compare size in kb : `a=$(du -sk ~ | awk '{print$1}')` and [ ${a} -gt 51200 ]